# solving a maze in java

Tags: java, search, maze

i am trying to solve a maze using either BFS or DFS, the maze numbers are given in a text file so i have to read line by line then convert each string to integers and store each line in an array of size 2 then i store this array in an arraylist.
secondly in the findRow method i try to search each element in the array and print out the numbers related to it either left or right.
but my main goal is to use any search method print out the fastest way to the end of the maze. the text file is in this format 0 and 1 is the starting and ending node.
11 3
2 3
0 3
1 4
5 4
5 7
6 7
7 8
8 9
9 10
0 5

================

## my code

```
public class Mazes {
    ArrayList<int[]> collections = new ArrayList();

    public String toString() {
        String result = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < collections.size(); i++) {
            result += collections.get(i)[0];
            result += " ";
            result += collections.get(i)[1];
            result += "\n";
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void getMazes() throws Exception{
        try{
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:\\csd3939\\maze1.txt");
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine;

            while((strLine = br.readLine()) !=  null){
                String[] splitStringArray = strLine.split(" ");
                int[] intElementArray = new int[2];
                for(int i=0; i<splitStringArray.length; i++){
                    intElementArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitStringArray[i]);                     }
                collections.add(intElementArray);
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
            in.close();

        }catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> findRowConnection(int rowID){
        ArrayList<Integer> connectRow = new ArrayList();
        for(int i=0; i<collections.size(); i++){
            int[] searching = collections.get(i);
            if(rowID == searching[0]){
                connectRow.add(searching[1]);
            }
            if(rowID == searching[1]){
                connectRow.add(searching[0]);
            }
        }
        return connectRow;
    }
}

===========
main method
===========

public class MazeMain {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
        Mazes mainmaze = new Mazes();
        mainmaze.getMazes();
        System.out.println(mainmaze);
        ArrayList<Integer> searchResult = mainmaze.findRowConnection(0);

        System.out.println("Connected Rows are :");
        for(int i=0; i<searchResult.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(searchResult.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is your actual question? Also, what is the structure of the text file? What do the numbers mean? How does the maze work in theory?

Comment: the structure of the text file are in rows and columns 2 numbers in a row separated by space, the final code will search through the array which is the text file
the way it works is that the code is supposed to print the path that leads to the end node which is 1, from a given root node
for example let say 3 was given as the rootnode the program should search the child node of 3, and search the childnode of the childnode of 3 and keep searching until it find 1. and then prints the path from 3 to 1
example structure of file
3 0
4 6
8 9
7 3
1 2